# Wrong dimensions - android

Tags: android, text, dimensions

I have an edittext with its textsize set in the layout and  another one with the size set programmatically, but what is supposed to be the same size, doesn't match, its bigger.
For performance i don't want to use:

```
setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 65);
```

(that works well). I want to make the calculation before, so I tryed:

```
    sm = (float) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    sm = (float) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dsma);
```

with

```
<dimen name="dsma">18sp</dimen>
```

in dimens.
And then

```
edit.settextsize(sm);
```

Both gives me big a big font. Fix? tnx.

Comment: and how do you set sm later?

Comment: read the docs on edit.settextsize(sm);

Comment: it says"Set the default text size to the given value, interpreted as "scaled pixel" units. This size is adjusted based on the current density and user font size preference."

Comment: exactly:  scaled pixels but you pass raw pixels

Comment: i thought theyr converted by the functions... so you have the solution ?

Comment: sure,  call setText with two args

Comment: there must be a way to do it separately!

Comment: see the sources of TextView.setTextSize(float) and everything will be clear

Comment: so i hope you know how to set text size ?

Comment: yep, the answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
edit.setTextSize(18);
```

Theres no way to avoid the calculation, since its done anyway, a simple int(float) will be considered sp.

Credits to pskink, tnx.